# minicom script send double enter?

Tags: minicom

I am trying to use minicom script.
What I want from script is after I open up the minicom with

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyACM0 -S script.txt
```

where script.txt stores all command

```
send "\n\n"
send "lec"
```

the very first command I want to send is double enter ("enter key" twice)
Then, send lec to get data

However, whenever I run the command only "@" is showed up.
I saw https://linux.die.net/man/1/runscript that

```
send "\n"
```

is recongzing new line so that is why I put

```
sned "\n\n"
```

for double enter.

Any advice would be appreciated!